# Proving the set $R$ is finite

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Suppose $L$ is a regular language. Let $R\subseteq L$ be a language with maximal size such that for each $x,y\in R$ neither $x$ be a substring of $y$ after removing a substring from $y$ nor $y$  become a substring of $x$ after removing a substring from $x$. Could we conclude that $R$ is finite?

My thoughts are as follows:

We know our alphabet is finite, also each string on $\Sigma^*$ is finite, I tried to use those facts to prove that $|R|$ is finite but  I got stuck. Any hint will appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what "be a substring of $y$ after removing a substring from $y$" means?  How does this differ from "be a substring of $y$"?  They look equivalent to me, so I'm not sure why you've stated it in the more complicated manner, and I wonder if I am misunderstanding.  Can you define that concept precisely, using mathematics and $\forall,\exists$ quantifier?  Can you give an example where the two notions differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists an infinite sequence of strings, such that no string is a substring of another. For example $a b^* a$.

If one considers the subsequence ordering instead of the substring ordering, then every infinite set of strings has a pair such that one is a subsequence of the other. This is known as [Higman's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-quasi-ordering).

Comment: I make some mistakes in describing the problem statement. Could you look at that again?

Comment: I do not understand what changes "after removing a substring from $y$". How is the relation between $x$ and $y$?